# ¿Como desactivo todos los elementos de un jpanel? en java

Tags: java

Lo intento de la siguiente manera:

```
jPanel.setEnabled(false);
```

Pero no funciona.

¿Hay otra opción?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías de forma básica obtener todos los componentes y desactivarlos, tal como se ve a continuación:

```
public void enableComponents(Container container, boolean enable) {
    Component[] components = container.getComponents();
    for (Component component : components) {
        component.setEnabled(enable);
        if (component instanceof Container) {
            enableComponents((Container)component, enable);
        }
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo se puede ver el atributo Container que sería tu JPanel ya que este extiende del primero como se ve en la documentación de [Container en la documentación de AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Container.html).

El ejemplo completo lo puedes revisar en [StackOverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985734/java-swing-enabling-disabling-all-components-in-jpanel).

Comment: Creada para ambos casos **activar/desactivar**. Gracias hermano.

Answer (score 3):

Con tu código lo que haces es "desactivar" el JPanel en sí (lo cual realmente no hace gran cosa).

Si quieres desactivar los elementos contenidos en el `JPanel`, tendrás que obtener la lista de estos elementos y recorrerla, desactivando cada elemento por separado.

```
for (Component component : jPanel.getComponents()) {
   component.setEnabled(false); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes bloquear cada uno de los elementos del panel por ejemplo:

```
jTextFile1.setEnabled(false);
jTextFile2.setEnabled(false);
```